# How to join two columns in one single query in my sql

Tags: mysql

I have a homework in sql where i am stuck in a question that says how many books we have about sports in english 
So i typed in mysql

```
Select count(category) 
From books
Where category= ‘sports’;
```

So how to add the language coulmn and make it count only the english version in sports

Comment: Select count(category) 
From books
Where category= 'sports' and language= 'english';

Comment: language column is in books table or in another table? I think description is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a column by the name `language` in the `books` table, the following query should work

```
Select count(category) 
from books
where category= ‘sports’ and language= 'english';
```